# typescript: How would you return a new function with the same arguments but different types for those arguments?

Tags: typescript

```js
const stringToDate = ( x: string ) => new Date( x )
//    stringToDate: (x: string) => Date

type MapTupleValues<Tuple extends any[], NewValue> = {
    [ index in keyof Tuple ]: NewValue
}

type TestMappedTuple = MapTupleValues<[ a: Date, b: Date ], string>
//   TestMappedTuple = [a: string, b: string]
// works fine

function modifyFn<Fn extends ( ...args: Date[] ) => any> ( fn: Fn ) {
    return ( ...args: MapTupleValues<Parameters<Fn>, string> ): ReturnType<Fn> => {
        //   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ error
        //   A rest parameter must be of an array type.

        return fn( ...args.map( x => stringToDate( x ) ) )
    }
}

const daysDifference = ( start: Date, end: Date ) => ( end.getTime() - start.getTime() ) / ( 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 )
//    daysDifference: (start: Date, end: Date) => number

const modifiedDaysDifference = modifyFn( daysDifference )
//    modifiedDaysDifference: (start: string, end: string) => number

console.log( daysDifference( new Date( '2022-07-29' ), new Date( '2022-08-21' ) ) ) // 23
console.log( modifiedDaysDifference( '2022-07-29', '2022-08-21' ) ) // 23
```

this seems to be working, even though there is an error in `modifyFn`

how can I get rid of the error while still getting the same result?

Comment: Is your primary question "how can I get rid of the error while still getting the same result?" from the body of the post? Or is it "how do I return a new function with the same arguments..." from the title?  If it's the question in the body, then [this](https://tsplay.dev/NrnPlN) is how I'd approach it.  If it's the question in the title, then [this](https://tsplay.dev/N913oN) is.  Let me know which if any of those you'd like to see written up as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks jcalz

Here's their answer:

```js
const stringToDate = (x: string) => new Date(x)
//    stringToDate: (x: string) => Date

type MapTupleValues<T extends any[], V> = Extract<{
    [I in keyof T]: V
}, any[]>

type TestMappedTuple = MapTupleValues<[a: Date, b: Date], string>
//   TestMappedTuple = [a: string, b: string]
// works fine

function modifyFn<Fn extends (...args: Date[]) => any>(fn: Fn) {
    return (...args: MapTupleValues<Parameters<Fn>, string>): ReturnType<Fn> => {
        return fn(...args.map(x => stringToDate(x)))
    }
}

const daysDifference = (start: Date, end: Date) => (end.getTime() - start.getTime()) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)
//    daysDifference: (start: Date, end: Date) => number

const modifiedDaysDifference = modifyFn(daysDifference)
//    modifiedDaysDifference: (start: string, end: string) => number

console.log(daysDifference(new Date('2022-07-29'), new Date('2022-08-21'))) // 23
console.log(modifiedDaysDifference('2022-07-29', '2022-08-21')) // 23
```

Comment: My intent was to write up my own answer with explanations, once you replied to my comment asking for clarification on your question.  Could you answer that and I could possibly post my own answer?  Or could you add context to this explaining what's going on?